# how to autoselect by ip format in semantic ui and how to prevent autoslect of added ones in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, semantic-ui

[image]
[image]
Setting the forceSelection property to false fixes this problem
but then when I manually add it myself as 5.5.5.5 it is not selected

[image]

When I enter 5.5.5.5 and click anywhere I want it to be added.
how can I do that

```js
  ipDropdown.dropdown({
            action: function (text, value,$selectedItem) {
               if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(value)) {
                  $(this).dropdown('set selected', value);
                   
               }
               else if (_.isEmpty(ipDropdown.dropdown('get value'))) 
               {
                   
               }
            },
            allowAdditions: true,
            forceSelection: true,
            allowReselection:true,
            onAdd: function (value, text) {
               
                ipList.push(text); 
            },
            onRemove: function (value, text) {
                ipList = arrayRemove(ipList, text)
            },
        });
```